# How to ignore "-Ywarn-unused" warning in Scala?

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, lint, suppress-warnings

How do I ignore "Ywarn-unused" warning for a piece of code in Scala? I want it to be enabled generally, but I want to make an exclusion for a particular class (or, say, method). How do I do that?

The code in question is macro-generated, so I have no power over it (though I raised an issue for the library that generates the strange code https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues/641).

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/ghik/silencer?

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain I think it could actually solve the problem. Via an external dependency though. But big thanks for an alternative, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

in build.sbt

```
val silencerVersion = "1.4.4"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  compilerPlugin("com.github.ghik" % "silencer-plugin" % silencerVersion cross CrossVersion.full),
  "com.github.ghik" % "silencer-lib" % silencerVersion % Provided cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

If you want to filter only certain paths:

```
scalacOptions += "-P:silencer:pathFilters=reactivemongo"
```